# Android: Retrofit beta2.0 ServiceClass with interface. Unable to understand why use interface when it is not using

Tags: android, retrofit

I don't know my interface is not working. when I am changing my `URL` in interface the program works. But When i change my `URL` from `REQUEST` then error occurs. What's the reason. Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance

```
public class Service{
private static GitApiInterface gitApiInterface;
private static final String baseUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/channels/";

public static GitApiInterface getClient() {
    if (gitApiInterface == null) {
        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(baseUrl + "staffpicks/videos")
                        .get()
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                        .build();
                Log.e("Request ", "" + request.url());

                Response response = chain.proceed(request);                    
                return response;
            }
        });

        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okClient)
                .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverter())
                .build();
        gitApiInterface = client.create(GitApiInterface.class);
    }
    return gitApiInterface;
}


public interface GitApiInterface {

    @GET("staffpicks/videos")
    Call<String> getVimeoVideoData();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is url is being "https://api.vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/videosstaffpicks/videos". Because you are adding "staffpicks/videos" twice.

Retrofit automagically adds given annotations which represents methods in interfaces to end of base url.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(baseUrl + "staffpicks/videos")
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .build();
```

In this section ".url()" is supposed to used for base urls.

Comment: I am getting output result and my url is like "https://api.vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/videos"

Comment: But this urls comes from your interceptor. Your final object which is Retrofit's urls is different.

Comment: If i modify something in  ".url(baseUrl + "staffpicks/videos")" this line they i would get error 404. But when i change url in " @GET("staffpicks/videos")" programs run successfull.

Comment: ".url(baseUrl)" you can try this. It should work and keep your @GET

Comment: request object should be single instance also.

Comment: Think like that, you have single client instance for communicating with backend, also you should have single interceptor instance that integrates with it.

Comment: If i add .url(baseUrl) then it is taking only base url, not appending this " @GET("staffpicks/videos")"

Comment: Retrofit autmatically adds it.

Comment: So you can use another interface with your "Retrofit client" object. This is why retrofit is easy to use and how it works. :)

Comment: I strongly advice you to read more about retrofit. Otherwise your structure could have problems if you dont.

Comment: I am not getting anything of this.... Please do you have any material please share it. There is online material but not sufficient.

Comment: I got the Solution: Just have to remove some thing  

                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                    return response;
in intercept() method. that's it

Comment: Its great that works. :) 
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors Here is reference what chain.proceed does. I did not know that much :)